# md-select - how to force required?

Tags: html, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

How do I force `md-select` in multiple mode to behave just like

```
<select multiple required ... >
```

?

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXrWEV) is the fiddle, to show what I mean. In this example, my browser doesn't let me submit form without selecting at least 1 option from the select tag.

I want md-select to behave similarly, but I don't know how can I do that - neither putting 'required' attribute nor adding 'ng-require' directive helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rely on Angular to do the validation for this, rather than the browser.  Here's my forked example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVGLZV

Specifically:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">submit</button>
```

To keep the submit button disabled until the form is valid and,

```
<form novalidate name="myForm">
```

To name the form and tell the browser not to do its own validation on it.

You could even add some CSS class for ng-invalid to show red around the invalid fields.

EDIT: Make sure you put an `ng-model` on your `<select multiple>`, otherwise the required attribute won't work.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can play with novalidate and angular. But is there any way to rely on browser? I'd like to avoid the need of writing custom css for error messages right now.

Comment: I played around with it for a bit, but I can't seem to get it to work. md-select isn't a form element, thus I think browser form validation won't be triggered on it.

Comment: I checked your snippet once again and there is a strange behaviour: if you select an option in md-select and select box, button is active. But it doesn't deactivate i you deselect md-select values completely.

Comment: This doesn't seem like intended behavior. I actually came across your Github post while trying to find a solution, so let me know how that goes. There are probably hacky ways to get around it, like putting a $watch on the states and resetting it to the empty string if it's an empty array.

Comment: As already mentioned, from a good UI perspective it is important to highlight the error fields with a custom message than just disable the submit button (which a lot of people do). Think of it from the user perspective, it is important to tell the user why the button is disabled then just disabling it until the form is valid (programmer perspective)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to disable submit button but instead trigger error when submit button is hit, you can set the $touched property to true to trigger required alert

```
yourFormName.mdseletName.$touched=true;
```